# Scraping the user portal for the CDC Wonder API

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Sorry in advance for the novel, I've tried to distill this down into something short and sweet, but find it impossible. I'm really hoping someone can shed some light on this problem.

The project: to build a set of utilities to make using the CDC Wonder API easier.

The Wonder API has several endpoints, in the format of `/D140` or `/D76`, for example.

The endpoint must be hit with a POST request, with a set of query parameters sent as an xml string as a POST data parameter.

The query parameter xml string is complicated. The basic format is

```
<parameter>
<name></name>
<value></value>
</parameter>
</request-parameters>
```

The names and values are best understood by going to the user-facing query portal. Each one of the inputs (forms, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc) corresponds to a query parameter. Each parameter name is in the form of a code, such as `D76.V9` or `O_V27fmode`. The value may also be a code, or occasionally could be plaintext, such as `*All*`.

Each endpoint requires a slightly different set of parameters, and the coding for the values is also different. The CDC does not provide documentation on which parameters each endpoint expects. Their documentation specifically tells you that the best way to find this information is by examining the source code of the user-facing query portal, where each element has its name and value embedded as an attribute.

I've found that you can also retrieve these parameters by opening up the dev tools network tab, submitting a filled out query form, and, after the new page loads with your results, checking the POST call's header form data.

One of the utilities I'm trying to build is to scrape the query portal page and programmatically extract the names and values of all parameters from the HTML source code. Seems simple enough and I think I know how to do it.

But, here's the rub: the URL of the user-facing query portal is the same as the URL for the endpoint that you call. In a web browser, going to this URL (https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/datarequest/D76) sends you to the query form that you fill out. But when you use that same URL in a request in Python, it expects an xml string of query parameters, otherwise you will get an error.

Is it possible to use the requests library to hit this user portal? I tried setting the referrer to https://wonder.cdc.gov/ucd-icd10.html, which is a page you're redirected to before you can get to the query portal, and you must agree to the terms and conditions. I also tried pulling the form data out of the network tab and sent it as an xml string with my POST request, and got a 500 back -- it's expecting the query parameters (including a specific parameter agreeing to the terms of use, as outlined in the documentation). Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
xml_string =  '''<query-parameters>
<parameter><name>stage</name> <value>about</value> </parameter> <parameter> <name>saved_id</name> <value></value> </parameter> <parameter> <name>action-I Agree</name> <value>I Agree</value> </parameter> </query-parameters> '''
data = {'request_xml': xml_string}
response = requests.post('https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/datarequest/D76')
print(response.text) 
print(response)
```

Really curious to know how to crack this nut, what am I missing here? How should I be approaching this problem?

Comment: Why not just download the zips directly? https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data_access/VitalStatsOnline.htm#Mortality_Multiple

Comment: That helps getting the actual data, but I'm really interested in understanding what's going on and how to solve the problem with code.

Answer (score 0):

Long time after you asked the question but I think the issue is with the post request is made and also the contents of your data variable.

Also just a note that it should be 'result-parameters' instead of 'query-parameters' in your xml_string.

It does seem that the documentation has improved a lot:
https://github.com/alipphardt/cdc-wonder-api/blob/master/CDC%2BWONDER%2BAPI%2BExample.ipynb

Here's how I think you can fix this:

```
xml_string = \
            '''<query-parameters>
                <parameter>
                    <name>stage</name> 
                    <value>about</value> 
                </parameter> 
                <parameter> 
                    <name>saved_id</name> 
                    <value></value> 
                </parameter>
            </query-parameters> '''

url = 'https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/datarequest/D76' ## or D140
param_name = 'request_xml'

url = "https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/datarequest/D76"
response = requests.post(url, data={"request_xml": xml_string, "accept_datause_restrictions": "true"})
```